# Timer in separate thread

Tags: c#, timer

I want to create a timer in a separate thread, but I'm not sure how to do it. 
The timer should stop after clicking button a button.

Below I have an example that mostly works but it stops sometimes for 1-2 seconds when the loop is executing. So I guess I have to put it in a separate thread?  This is what I've tried:

```
    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    public void TimeThread()
    {
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Timer));
        th.Start();
    }

    public void Timer()
    {
        var delta = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        textBoxSeconds.Text = delta.Seconds.ToString("n0");
        textBoxMinutes.Text = Math.Floor(delta.TotalMinutes).ToString("n0");
    }
```

---

EDIT:
So here is all the code that I have, still not exactly sure how to put the timer in separate thread.

```
namespace Imgur
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool flag = true;
        int downloadedNumber = 0;
        private DateTime startTime;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonStart.Enabled = false;
            buttonStop.Enabled = true;
            if (!flag)
            {
                flag = true;
            }

            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            timer1.Start();


            for (int i=0;i<100000 && flag;i++)
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                string pic1 = rnd_str(5);
                string pic2 = ".jpg";
                string picture = pic1 + pic2;

                //********** GETTING SIZE OF IMAGE ***********
                Size sz = GetSize("http://i.imgur.com/" + picture);
                string imageSize = (sz.Width.ToString() + " " + sz.Height.ToString()); ;
                //********************************************

                if(imageSize != "161 81")
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFile("http://i.imgur.com/" + picture, @"e:\test\" + picture);
                    richTextBox1.Text += String.Format("Downloaded picture: {0}\r\n", picture);
                    downloadedNumber++;
                    textBoxDownloadedNumber.Text = string.Format("{0}", downloadedNumber);
                }
                webClient.Dispose();
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (i == 999995)
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            richTextBox1.Text += "End Dowloaded Session \n";
            buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            buttonStop.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        public static Size GetSize(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "image/gif";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s);
            Size sz = new Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            return sz;
        }

        public static string rnd_str(int liczba_liter)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int char_type;
            string return_string = "";
            int i =0;
            for (i = 0; i < liczba_liter; i++)
            {
                if (r.Next(1, 3) == 1)
                {
                    char_type = r.Next(1, 4);
                    switch (char_type)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            return_string += (char)r.Next(48, 58); // convertion int -> ASCII character; 48-57 are ASCII digits
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            return_string += (char)r.Next(97, 123); // convertion int -> ASCII character; as above but small letters
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            return_string += (char)r.Next(65, 91); // as above; large letters
                            break;
                        default:
                            i -= 1;
                            break;//do not add any letter if no type is allowed
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    i -= 1;
                    return_string += "";
                }
            }
            return return_string;
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flag = false;
            buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var delta = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            textBoxSeconds.Text = delta.Seconds.ToString("n0");
            textBoxMinutes.Text = Math.Floor(delta.TotalMinutes).ToString("n0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Timer is already in a (seperate) thread. There is something else going on.

Comment: The code makes no sense.  What "loop"?

Comment: What is the type of `timer1`, with namespace?

Comment: Why do you ask a question if you don't care about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems there is no connection between the timer and the print of the time passed.
You need to pay attention because it isn't possible to change GUI elements from another thread that isn't the main one.
To do this you need to use Invoke in WinForms

```
if (control.InvokeRequired)
  {
    control.Invoke(new SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(SetControlPropertyThreadSafe), new object[] { control, propertyName, propertyValue });
  }
  else
  {
    control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, control, new object[] { propertyValue });
  }
```

or dispatcher in WPF/SL - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

In order to use another thread and you have some options:

1. Threadpool (On .Net 4) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx
2. Thread class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx
3. BackgroundWorker Class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

The 3rd option is the easiest if you don't know how to work with theards

Answer (score 0):

There're tree Timers in .Net take a look at the following article and select correct [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) looks like you need timer from `System.Threading`, not from `System.Windows.Forms`.